# How do I mount a Union filesystem under Centos

Tags: centos

I did some work on a Centos LiveUSB system. I created some files etc.

I later moved to a complete linux install and want to read the previous LiveUSB filesytem straight from the usb key.

From my research, the LiveUSB seems to use a Union filesystem.

I think these are the files that form the data of the filesystems.

```
[root@hostname ~]# ls /mnt/hgfs/H_UsbKey/LiveOS/ -lah
total 2.8G
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Dec 16 04:32 .
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Dec 31  1979 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  28K Dec 16 04:32 livecd-iso-to-disk
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12K Dec 15 07:32 osmin.img
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4.0G Mar  9 23:56 overlay-LIVE-C060-D3BD
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1.6G Dec 15 03:41 squashfs.img
```